# Верстка изогнутых границ блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, svg

Нужно сверстать блок с изогнутыми границами, что-то типо как на изображении,
причем очень важно, чтобы можно было в границы такого блока вставлять разный контент (картинки, видео, другие блоки) и он обрезался внутри этого блока.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дизайнер провел кисточкой, верстальщик - страдай!) Смотрите в сторону «bezier curve clip path»

Comment: Используйте svg

Comment: Да сделай два блока и нижнему поставь эту изогнутую картинку png на бекграунд. И если нужно нижний спозиционируй абсолютом

Answer (score 5):

Для вашего случая - попросите дизайнера создать соотв. `svg`

Пример

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #000 url(https://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/behr-zoom-background-feature-2020-600x315.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 7vw;
  position: relative;
}

.section__shape {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  section

  <svg class="section__shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
  <path fill="currentColor" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,192L60,192C120,192,240,192,360,170.7C480,149,600,107,720,117.3C840,128,960,192,1080,192C1200,192,1320,128,1380,96L1440,64L1440,0L1380,0C1320,0,1200,0,1080,0C960,0,840,0,720,0C600,0,480,0,360,0C240,0,120,0,60,0L0,0Z"></path>
</svg>
</section>
```

Comment: бро, спасибо тебе огромное, ты спас мне жизнь=)